# CAS 5.2.4 cas.properties location

Tags: ldap, cas

I'm using CAS 5.2.4, deployed on Tomcat 9.0.8, running on Windows 10. I want to connect to LDAP, but I don't know where the cas.properties has to be placed.

I have already placed it in :
C:\etc\cas
C:\etc\cas\config
'tomcat'\cas\etc\cas
'tomcat'\cas\WEB-INF\classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I changed the property **spring.profiles.active**, I set it as production, now I change it, again, to **standalone**.

When the **stand alone profile** is active CAS search extra configurations in **/etc/cas/config** in particular the file **standalone.properties**.

When the production profile is active CAS doen not search more configuration files, except if the spring cloud is configurated.

Comment: Using CAS 5.3.6 in tomcat 9 and having set the environment variable SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = local did not take the configuration / etc / cas ...
Once set as SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = standalone take the correct settings.
This is a problem if CAS lives with other applications that use Spring profile with other values.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running 5.2.4 or 5.3.4? Given there is no such thing as 5.3.4, you may want to correct the question.

Also note that tomcat 9 is officially not supported.

Properties by default go to c:\etc\cas\config on Windows, which is the same path as /etc/cas/config on Linux. The initial "/" on windows is translated to be the root drive, which for you might be "c:".

Comment: Sorry, is the 5.2.4 as the title says, but actually it is runing very well on tomcat 9 except by the properties files.

Comment: Yes, those should do it. The properties try to auto-configure tomcat in such a way that impact breaking APIs between 8 and 9.

Comment: Thansk, that is a problem.

By the way I solve it writing the LDAP configuration in the application.properties (I did not want it but it works) and the jsons services consfiguration in the "cas/WEB-INF/classes/service" folder.

Thanks, Misagh Moayyed.